# Import txt files onto single worksheet and add filename in column 1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA coding, I recieve raw field data text files from survey equipment i would like arranged in a summary table in a new worksheet; i have a code to import multiple text files by appending each file into a single table, however the raw data files contain too many rows not required in the summary. Out of approximately 1000 rows output in each text file, only 16 are needed for my summary table. The data is arranged based on each test No, therefore 'ROWIDs' in 'column 2' are identical for the metrics reported.

I would like help creating code to add txt filename without .txt during import, i.e 'Filename1'  on each row in column 1 for records imported from the specific txt file and to loop through the raw data sheet based on 'Column 1' as 'TestID' , 'Column 2' as 'ROWID' then copy values in the 'Column 4' into summary sheet, sample output below, 
- Also would like code to just append new imported txt files at the last row in the same worksheet. 
@Ahamed AU your help so far is greatly appreciated!!

```
5100,FILE NAME & SYSTEM MODEL              : Z:\FRICTION\FRICTION_2019\TESTING\test_file\filename1.txt  1295 PAVEMENT FRICTION TESTER (UNIVERSAL)
5101,SOFTWARE VERSION                      : 1.0.6506.22298
5101A,VCU SOFTWARE VERSION                 : 8000908.601.007a
5102,TIME                       (hh:mm:ss) : 11:44:13
5103,DATE                     (mm/dd/yyyy) : 01/22/2019
5104,SYSTEM UNITS                          : US (ENGLISH)
5105,TEST TYPE                             : STANDARD
5106,TARGET SPEED                    (mph) : 40.0
5107,TEST WHEEL                            : LEFT
5108,TEST LUBRICANT                        : WET
5109,DATA FILTER                           : 5 POINTS
5110,CYCLE TYPE                            : MANUAL
5111,CYCLE DWELL DISTANCE             (ft) : 528.0
5112,WATER CONTROL                         : WATER OFF AFTER TEST
5113,NOZZLE CONTROL                        : RAISE NOZZLE ON BACKUP
5114,TIME PARAMETER - T1         (seconds) : 0.500
5115,TIME PARAMETER - T2         (seconds) : 2.000
5116,TIME PARAMETER - T3         (seconds) : 0.500
5117,TIME PARAMETER - T4         (seconds) : 1.000
5118,TIME PARAMETER - T5         (seconds) : 0.100
5145,VEHICLE ENCODER SF         (in/pulse) : 0.47803
5146,LEFT ENCODER SF            (in/pulse) : 0.50493
5147,RIGHT ENCODER SF           (in/pulse) : 0.49165
5148,ENCODER CAL LENGTH               (ft) : 1056.0
5149,ENCODER CALIBRATION TIME   (hh:mm:ss) : 13:39:28
5150,ENCODER CALIBRATION DATE (mm/dd/yyyy) : 01/09/2019
5151,TRAILER WHEEL WEIGHT             (lb) : 1085.00
5152,FORCE TRANSDUCERS                     : LEFT
5153,LEFT TRACTION CAL VALUE          (lb) : 455.00
5154,LEFT LOAD CAL VALUE              (lb) : 466.00
5155,LEFT TRACTION GAIN          (lb/volt) : 500.607
5156,LEFT TRACTION OFFSET             (lb) : -11.542
5157,LEFT LOAD GAIN              (lb/volt) : 499.589
5158,LEFT LOAD OFFSET                 (lb) : -23.584
5159,RIGHT TRACTION CAL VALUE         (lb) : 450.00
5160,RIGHT LOAD CAL VALUE             (lb) : 450.00
5161,RIGHT TRACTION GAIN         (lb/volt) : 495.000
5162,RIGHT TRACTION OFFSET            (lb) : 6.199
5163,RIGHT LOAD GAIN             (lb/volt) : 495.000
5164,RIGHT LOAD OFFSET                (lb) : 18.799
5165,SYSTEM CALIBRATION TIME    (hh:mm:ss) : 11:38:03
5166,SYSTEM CALIBRATION DATE  (mm/dd/yyyy) : 01/22/2019
5167,SPEED RANGE TOLERANCE       (+/- mph) : 1.5
5168,WATER DEPTH SETTING              (mm) : 0.5
0000,=================================================================
0000, Test Summary Values              , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
5000, Test Number                      , 1             , 
5001, Route                            ,               , 
5002, Direction                        ,               , 
5003, Lane                             ,               , 
5004, Event                            ,               , 
5005, Test Start DMI                   , 0.00          , ft
5006, Test Start Time (Hr)             , 11            , hr
5007, Test Start Time (Min)            , 40            , minute
5008, Test Wheel                       , Left          , 
5009, Test Wet/Dry                     , WET           , 
5010, Latitude                         , 034.0564687° N, 
5011, Longitude                        , 084.3002236° W, 
5012, Bearing                          , 179.9         , degrees
6000, Air Temperature                  , -3.5          , f
6001, Surface Temperature              , 55.6          , f
6002, Left Tire Temperature            , not installed , f
6003, Left Nozzle Water Temperature    , 0.0           , f
6004, Right Tire Temperature           , not installed , f
6005, Right Nozzle Water Temperature   , not installed , f

5100,FILE NAME & SYSTEM MODEL              : Filename2.txt 1295 PAVEMENT FRICTION TESTER (UNIVERSAL)
5101,SOFTWARE VERSION                      : 1.0.6506.22298
5101A,VCU SOFTWARE VERSION                 : 8000908.601.007a
5102,TIME                       (hh:mm:ss) : 11:44:13
5103,DATE                     (mm/dd/yyyy) : 01/22/2019
5104,SYSTEM UNITS                          : US (ENGLISH)
5105,TEST TYPE                             : STANDARD
5106,TARGET SPEED                    (mph) : 40.0
5107,TEST WHEEL                            : LEFT
5108,TEST LUBRICANT                        : WET
5109,DATA FILTER                           : 5 POINTS
5110,CYCLE TYPE                            : MANUAL
5111,CYCLE DWELL DISTANCE             (ft) : 528.0
5112,WATER CONTROL                         : WATER OFF AFTER TEST
5113,NOZZLE CONTROL                        : RAISE NOZZLE ON BACKUP
5114,TIME PARAMETER - T1         (seconds) : 0.500
5115,TIME PARAMETER - T2         (seconds) : 2.000
5116,TIME PARAMETER - T3         (seconds) : 0.500
5117,TIME PARAMETER - T4         (seconds) : 1.000
5118,TIME PARAMETER - T5         (seconds) : 0.100
5119,DMI UNITS                             : FEET
5120,DMI COUNT DIRECTION                   : UP
5121,DMI REFERENCE START              (ft) : 0.000
5122,START MODE                            : START TEST BY PENDANT AT DMI START
5123,START DISTANCE                   (ft) : 100.000
5124,DISPLAY PARAMETER                     : SN AVERAGE
5125,DISPLAY SETTING                       : TEST SAMPLES GRAPH
5126,SUMMARY DATA STORAGE                  : ON
5127,RAW DATA STORAGE                      : ON
5128,PRINTING                              : OFF
5129,PUMP SOURCE                           : LEFT PUMP = TANK 1   RIGHT PUMP = TANK 1
5130,FLOW METER 1 GAIN          (gpm/volt) : 9.500
5131,FLOW METER 1 OFFSET             (gpm) : 0.000
5134,AIR TEMPERATURE GAIN         (f/volt) : 13.999
5135,AIR TEMPERATURE OFFSET            (f) : 0.001
5136,SURFACE TEMPERATURE GAIN     (f/volt) : 22.500
5137,SURFACE TEMPERATURE OFFSET        (f) : -85.000
5140,GPS INSTALLED                         : YES
5141A,TANK1 TEMPERATURE GAIN      (f/volt) : 21.996
5141B,TANK1 TEMPERATURE OFFSET         (f) : 0.001
5145,VEHICLE ENCODER SF         (in/pulse) : 0.47803
5146,LEFT ENCODER SF            (in/pulse) : 0.50493
5147,RIGHT ENCODER SF           (in/pulse) : 0.49165
5148,ENCODER CAL LENGTH               (ft) : 1056.0
5149,ENCODER CALIBRATION TIME   (hh:mm:ss) : 13:39:28
5150,ENCODER CALIBRATION DATE (mm/dd/yyyy) : 01/09/2019
5151,TRAILER WHEEL WEIGHT             (lb) : 1085.00
5152,FORCE TRANSDUCERS                     : LEFT
5153,LEFT TRACTION CAL VALUE          (lb) : 455.00
5154,LEFT LOAD CAL VALUE              (lb) : 466.00
5155,LEFT TRACTION GAIN          (lb/volt) : 500.607
5156,LEFT TRACTION OFFSET             (lb) : -11.542
5157,LEFT LOAD GAIN              (lb/volt) : 499.589
5158,LEFT LOAD OFFSET                 (lb) : -23.584
5159,RIGHT TRACTION CAL VALUE         (lb) : 450.00
5160,RIGHT LOAD CAL VALUE             (lb) : 450.00
5161,RIGHT TRACTION GAIN         (lb/volt) : 495.000
5162,RIGHT TRACTION OFFSET            (lb) : 6.199
5163,RIGHT LOAD GAIN             (lb/volt) : 495.000
5164,RIGHT LOAD OFFSET                (lb) : 18.799
5165,SYSTEM CALIBRATION TIME    (hh:mm:ss) : 11:38:03
5166,SYSTEM CALIBRATION DATE  (mm/dd/yyyy) : 01/22/2019
5167,SPEED RANGE TOLERANCE       (+/- mph) : 1.5
5168,WATER DEPTH SETTING              (mm) : 0.5
0000,=================================================================
0000, Test Summary Values              , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
5000, Test Number                      , 2             , 
5001, Route                            ,               , 
5002, Direction                        ,               , 
5003, Lane                             ,               , 
5004, Event                            ,               , 
5005, Test Start DMI                   , 29.36         , ft
5006, Test Start Time (Hr)             , 11            , hr
5007, Test Start Time (Min)            , 41            , minute
5008, Test Wheel                       , Left          , 
5009, Test Wet/Dry                     , WET           , 
5010, Latitude                         , 034.0511896° N, 
5011, Longitude                        , 084.3033369° W, 
5012, Bearing                          , 201.9         , degrees
6000, Air Temperature                  , -1.6          , f
6001, Surface Temperature              , 49.9          , f
6002, Left Tire Temperature            , not installed , f
6003, Left Nozzle Water Temperature    , 0.0           , f
6004, Right Tire Temperature           , not installed , f
6005, Right Nozzle Water Temperature   , not installed , f
6006, Tank 1 Water Temperature         , 0.0           , f
6007, Tank 2 Water Temperature         , not installed , f
6008, Tank 1 Water Level               , 353.3         , gal
6009, Tank 2 Water Level               , not installed , gal
6010, Data Filter                      , 5             , points
6011, Water Depth                      , 0.5           , mm
6012, Sampling Rate                    , 100           , hz
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Right Wheel Peak Values          , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6020, Right Traction Force             , 0.00          , lb
6021, Right Load Force                 , 0.00          , lb
6022, Right Vehicle Speed              , 0.0           , mph
6023, Right Test Wheel Speed           , 0.0           , mph
6024, Right SN                         , 0.00          , friction
6025, Right Percent Slip               , 0.0           , percent
6026, Right Time to Peak Brake Coef    , 0.00          , seconds
6027, Right Time to Wheel Lockup       , 0.00          , seconds
6028, Right Flow Rate                  , 0.0           , gpm
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Left Wheel Peak Values           , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6040, Left  Traction Force             , 880.60        , lb
6041, Left  Load Force                 , 959.17        , lb
6042, Left  Vehicle Speed              , 40.5          , mph
6043, Left  Test Wheel Speed           , 36.0          , mph
6044, Left  SN                         , 91.81         , friction
6045, Left  Percent Slip               , 11.2          , percent
6046, Left  Time to Peak Brake Coef    , 0.62          , seconds
6047, Left  Time to Wheel Lockup       , 0.76          , seconds
6048, Left  Flow Rate                  , 29.1          , gpm
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Right Wheel SN Values            , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6060, Right SN Average                 , 0.0           , friction
6061, Right SN Minimum                 , 0.0           , friction
6062, Right SN Maximum                 , 0.0           , friction
6063, Right SN Standard Deviation      , 0.0           , friction
6064, Right SN Speed Average           , 0.0           , mph
6065, Right SN Flow Average            , 0.0           , gpm
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Left Wheel SN Values             , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6080, Left  SN Average                 , 53.4          , friction
6081, Left  SN Minimum                 , 51.5          , friction
6082, Left  SN Maximum                 , 55.5          , friction
6083, Left  SN Standard Deviation      , 0.9           , friction
6084, Left  SN Speed Average           , 40.0          , mph
6085, Left  SN Flow Average            , 28.8          , gpm
0000,=================================================================
0000,=================================================================
0000, Test Summary Values              , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
5000, Test Number                      , 3             , 
5001, Route                            ,               , 
5002, Direction                        ,               , 
5003, Lane                             ,               , 
5004, Event                            ,               , 
5005, Test Start DMI                   , 411.62        , ft
5006, Test Start Time (Hr)             , 11            , hr
5007, Test Start Time (Min)            , 41            , minute
5008, Test Wheel                       , Left          , 
5009, Test Wet/Dry                     , WET           , 
5010, Latitude                         , 034.0501615° N, 
5011, Longitude                        , 084.3038254° W, 
5012, Bearing                          , 201.1         , degrees
6000, Air Temperature                  , -1.5          , f
6001, Surface Temperature              , 54.6          , f
6002, Left Tire Temperature            , not installed , f
6003, Left Nozzle Water Temperature    , 0.0           , f
6004, Right Tire Temperature           , not installed , f
6005, Right Nozzle Water Temperature   , not installed , f
6006, Tank 1 Water Temperature         , 0.0           , f
6007, Tank 2 Water Temperature         , not installed , f
6008, Tank 1 Water Level               , 326.0         , gal
6009, Tank 2 Water Level               , not installed , gal
6010, Data Filter                      , 5             , points
6011, Water Depth                      , 0.5           , mm
6012, Sampling Rate                    , 100           , hz
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Right Wheel Peak Values          , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6020, Right Traction Force             , 0.00          , lb
6021, Right Load Force                 , 0.00          , lb
6022, Right Vehicle Speed              , 0.0           , mph
6023, Right Test Wheel Speed           , 0.0           , mph
6024, Right SN                         , 0.00          , friction
6025, Right Percent Slip               , 0.0           , percent
6026, Right Time to Peak Brake Coef    , 0.00          , seconds
6027, Right Time to Wheel Lockup       , 0.00          , seconds
6028, Right Flow Rate                  , 0.0           , gpm
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Left Wheel Peak Values           , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6040, Left  Traction Force             , 814.08        , lb
6041, Left  Load Force                 , 907.37        , lb
6042, Left  Vehicle Speed              , 41.8          , mph
6043, Left  Test Wheel Speed           , 37.7          , mph
6044, Left  SN                         , 89.72         , friction
6045, Left  Percent Slip               , 9.9           , percent
6046, Left  Time to Peak Brake Coef    , 0.54          , seconds
6047, Left  Time to Wheel Lockup       , 0.71          , seconds
6048, Left  Flow Rate                  , 30.0          , gpm
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Right Wheel SN Values            , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6060, Right SN Average                 , 0.0           , friction
6061, Right SN Minimum                 , 0.0           , friction
6062, Right SN Maximum                 , 0.0           , friction
6063, Right SN Standard Deviation      , 0.0           , friction
6064, Right SN Speed Average           , 0.0           , mph
6065, Right SN Flow Average            , 0.0           , gpm
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
0000, Left Wheel SN Values             , Value         , Units
0000,-----------------------------------------------------------------
6080, Left  SN Average                 , 49.9          , friction
6081, Left  SN Minimum                 , 48.4          , friction
6082, Left  SN Maximum                 , 51.5          , friction
6083, Left  SN Standard Deviation      , 0.7           , friction
6084, Left  SN Speed Average           , 41.4          , mph
6085, Left  SN Flow Average            , 29.5          , gpm
0000,=================================================================
```

expected output summary table;
[expected output summary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0iqf.png)

Comment: Gideon could not understand question clearly as 1.you have given two sets of code. which one is to be modified? 2. What output you require. you said want to append last row only while file names are in first row only? May please provide sample desired output.

Comment: Hi @Ahamed AU, so i tried to modify 2nd code by adding the 1st code above after DO while....to be able to add the txt file name in the first column of the worksheet , FYI the filename is also found in the first row (5100) of the txt i.e.Z:\***\***\filename.txt  desired output ( Fixed width columns) e.g. row 5010 in sample data above would be;   filename 5010 Latitude 034.0564687° N. Then any subsequent imports should append to the same worksheet with corresponding txt file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try the Code below

```
Sub testNewFormat()
Dim Fno As Integer, Ln As String, Arr As Variant, RawArr As Variant
Dim TestNo As String, TestID As String, Wheel As String
Dim PrvTestNo As String, PrvTestID As String
Dim Rw As Long, FileNameLen As Integer
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim MyFile As Variant
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = True
   'Delete next line if file extention are not .sks
   .Filters.Add "SKS Files", "*.sks", 1

    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    Rw = 6
   'Next line would append data in excel File instead of Overwriting
   'Delete the line if want to overwrite Excel data
    Rw = Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each MyFile In .SelectedItems
    Fno = FreeFile
    Open MyFile For Input As #Fno

    PrvTestID = ""
    PrvTestNo = ""
    TestID = ""
    TestNo = ""
    Wheel = ""

        Do While Not EOF(Fno)    ' Loop until end of file.
        Line Input #Fno, Ln    ' Read line into variable.
        Arr = Split(Ln, ",")
           If UBound(Arr) = 1 And Trim(Arr(0)) = "5100" And InStr(1, UCase(Arr(1)), ".TXT") > 0 And InStr(1, Arr(1), ":") > 0 Then 'Test ID or FileNAme
                'FileName with Full Path wiyhout extension (.Txt)
                If InStr(1, UCase(Arr(1)), ".TXT") > InStr(1, Arr(1), ":") Then
                TestID = Mid(Arr(1), InStr(1, Arr(1), ":") + 1, InStr(1, UCase(Arr(1)), ".TXT") - InStr(1, Arr(1), ":") - 1)
                TestID = Trim(TestID)
                End If
                'FileName Stripped off Full Path And extension (.Txt)
                If InStr(1, TestID, "\") > 0 Then
                TestID = Right(TestID, Len(TestID) - InStrRev(TestID, "\"))
                End If

                If PrvTestID <> TestID Then
                Rw = Rw + 1
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = TestID
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = TestNo
                PrvTestID = TestID
                End If
           End If

            If UBound(Arr) >= 2 Then
              Select Case Trim(Arr(0))
              Case "5000"        'TestNo
              TestNo = Arr(2)
                    If PrvTestNo <> TestNo Then
                    If PrvTestNo <> "" Then Rw = Rw + 1
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = TestID
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = TestNo
                    PrvTestNo = TestNo
                    End If

                Case "5005"  'Distance
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 3).Value = Arr(2)
                Case "5006"    'Start Hr
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 4).Value = Arr(2)
                Case "5007"    'Start min
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 5).Value = Arr(2)
                Case "5008"    'Wheel
                Wheel = Arr(2)
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 6).Value = Wheel
                Case "5009"    'WetDry
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 7).Value = Arr(2)
                Case "5010"    'Lat
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 14).Value = Arr(2)
                Case "5011"   'Long
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 15).Value = Arr(2)
                Case "6001"    'Surface Temp
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 13).Value = Arr(2)
                End Select

                If Wheel = "Right" Then
                    Select Case Arr(0)
                    Case "6060"          'SN Average
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 9).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6061"          'SN Min
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 10).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6062"          'SN MAx
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 11).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6063"          'SN St Dev
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 12).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6064"          'Speed Avg
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 8).Value = Arr(2)
                    End Select
                Else
                    Select Case Arr(0)
                    Case "6080"          'SN Average
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 9).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6081"          'SN Min
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 10).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6082"          'SN MAx
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 11).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6083"          'SN St Dev
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 12).Value = Arr(2)
                    Case "6084"          'Speed Avg
                    Ws.Cells(Rw, 8).Value = Arr(2)
                    End Select
                End If
            End If
        Loop
Close #Fno

Next MyFile

End With

End Sub
```

the code edited for working with file name both with or without full path.

Output from  sample data

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ahamed AU, tested code and while it loops and gets the rows required, there are 3 issues with it;

Comment: Thanks @Ahamed AU, tested code and while it loops and gets the rows required, there are 3 issues with it; 1) Column 1 is blank, txt filename is not imported 2) When i import new txt files, rows that exist in the worksheet gets over-written if identical TestNo. already exists in the worksheet. 3) When i select multiple txt files to import at the same, the last row (last TestNo.) in each file is omitted. Could it be because the filename as a unique identifier is not getting populated?

Comment: @Gideon G I think you tested the code before editing (11 hrs ago). 1. The code edited for working with file name both with or without full path. 2. The code is designed to overwrite (starting from Row 7) . Editing again for appending. . 3. it is working OK with sample data.